# NameError: wrong constant name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_many` / `belongs_to` polymorphic relationship between two models, PointModifier and ManualPoints.

```
# ManualPoints Model
has_many :point_modifiers, as: :modifier

# PointModifier Model
belongs_to :modifier, polymorphic: true
```

I recently started seeing this error in my tests - `NameError: wrong constant name` - after adding `ActiveModel::Serializer` into my project. It does not appear to be related to `AMS`, and I've never seen this error before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little sleuthing revealed that this error appears to be related to constants.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NameError.html

Some more digging and I realized that the issue was related to my fixtures.

```
# PointModifiers Fixture
one:
  points: 2
  user_id: 1
  modifier_type: manual_points
  modifier_id: 1
```

The issue was that I had incorrectly used snake_case for the polymorphic relationship in the fixture. The solution is to use CamelCase, like this:

```
# PointModifiers Fixture
one:
  points: 2
  user_id: 1
  modifier_type: ManualPoints
  modifier_id: 1
```